# On Item Click Listener for List View extending ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

**What I have tried:**

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;

public EntryAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context,0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // // // //  NON-FUNCTIONING CODE BELOW 

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NewsItemActivity.class);
            convertView.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
}
```

The `AdapterView.onItemClickListener` doesnt yield any errors but doesnt seem to function whatsoever.

What is the proper way of setting this onClick Listener?

**Note:** I have to set it in this adapter class, not the main class for my own reasons.

Comment: Set the onClickListener on the convertView instead

Comment: Can you expand please. `convertView.setOnItemClickListener` ?

Comment: `convertView.setOnClickListener` doesnt give any errors except I cant seem to run the line `startActivity(intent)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the context initialized in the adapter constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shuldn't implement a listener inside the `getView()` unless you what set a listener on a particular view inside your row layout.

You should instead use `setOnItemClickListener()` method on your `ListView`:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_listview);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsItemActivity.class);
         context.startActivity(intent);
     } 
});
```

**EDIT**:

If, for each action inside the onclick, you need information that resides in your Objects (Item) then you can get it in this way:

```
Item item = (Item)listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

from inside of `onItemClick()` method

Comment: I have methods running inside my adapter class which returns values I need to pass through the intent. Hence the onClickListener in the adapter class

Comment: You can also get the selected content in OnItemClickListener itself by using adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).

Comment: Yes, you can use `getItem(position)` or `getItemAtPosition(position)`.  Basically `getItemAtPosition(position)` calls the adapter with `getItem(position)`.

Comment: What's the difference between `Item item = (Item) listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);` and `Item item = listArray.get(position)` where `listArray` is the array I pass into my adapter

Comment: Also if there is not relevant different, I always prefer the first one. If you mantain an external reference to the list inside the adapter you can cause problem. Or if your list is accidentally set to null, you lost your reference, but your list still exsists inside the adapter.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to edit the object properties inside the adapter, then access those objects as you showed above from outside the adapter class? This would solve my problem

Comment: i.e  can the objects inside the listArray be changed from inside the adapter class and then accessed from outside it?

Comment: I suggest you to change the list from inside the adapter and access it from outside, with `getItem(position)` mehtod.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83348/discussion-between-joseph82-and-gregory-peck).

Comment: I am using multiple columns in here, so how to display particular column with its position.?
`SimpleAdapter sAdap;
                sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(PendingOrderDetails.this, MyArrList, R.layout.pendordr_column, 
                  new String[]{"OrderID","Date","Name","Phone","Address","Product","Price","City","Username"}, 
                  new int[]{R.id.colorderid, R.id.coldate, R.id.colname, R.id.colphone, R.id.coladdress, R.id.colproduct, R.id.colprice,R.id.coluser});`

column Name

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Make what you want
        }
    });
```

Or depending on your item view, you can make the OnCLickListener on your global layout of the item or a specific item's layout

Comment: Cannot resolve startActivity. Other than this it seems to be giving no problems

Comment: Try with context.startActivity()

Comment: It gets rid of the error message, but the app crashes on start-up now

Comment: check for null on convertView

Answer (score 0):

Try by this code :-

```
Spinner cb_tv;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
list.add(phone1);
list.add(name1);
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Display_Tank.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
cb_tv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

cb_tv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

at the place of cb_tv Spinner You can use ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way... it is working in my case Change your `context` to
  `Activity activity = (Activity) context;`

```
       convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(activity, NewsItemActivity.class);
             activity.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: had to declare final... still app crashes on launch though

Comment: you can direct change it from your constructor in place of context it change to activity variable/instance and typecast this.

Comment: private Context context; is replace with private Activity context;  and this.context = context; is replace with this.context = (Activity)context;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best way to achieve this is to use your own ViewHolders in ListView.

**This is an example of a custom ViewHolder**

```
class MyViewHolder extends ViewHolder implements View.OnItemClickListener {
    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        /* Implement your views here
         * like this: mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myId);
         */
         view.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NewsItemActivity.class);
            convertView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

And on your getView method you create this ViewHolder and populate your Views with your data.