# Click listveiw does not work android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Why click Listview doesn't work?
I created a listview with an array adapter but the click line in the list view doesn't work.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(Listedesarticles.this, "List item was clicked at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: exactly where did you define your click listener in your code?

Comment: In oncreate after "mListView.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: I am asking about the method in which you are defining your click listener. Like in Adapter BindViewHolder or onCreate of Activity?

Comment: In oncreate after "mListView.setAdapter(adapter);"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31432139/12806124

Comment: No same problem

Answer (score 0):

i think this problem cause maybe:

1. your xml disabled ListView
2. ListView item layout has set setOnClickListener
3. your ListView's parent has intercepted touch event

Comment: `  <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="30.0sp"

        />`

Comment: Thank you for you, I solved my problem with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568006/13859811